# Portlet preferences

Tags: jsf-2, liferay, portlet

I'm trying to store portlet preferences in a backing bean (JSF) as mentioned in this [tutorial](http://www.portletfaces.org/doc/portletfaces-bridge/2.0.0/docbook/en-US/html/portletpreferences-and-jsf.html)

But, I can not understand how they imported Preference class here

`Map<String, Preference> mutablePreferenceMap =
            (Map<String, Preference>) elResolver.getValue(
                facesContext.getELContext(), null, elExpression);`

the package `javax.portlet.*` don't contain `faces.preference.Preference`

Anyone has an idea about that, specially how to save portlet preferences

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Liferay Faces Bridge JAR to your project.

Add the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>liferay-faces-alloy</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0-ga1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>liferay-faces-bridge-impl</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0-ga1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>liferay-faces-portal</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0-ga1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and the liferay-faces-bridge-api jar which is a dependency for liferay-faces-bridge-impl has this Preference interface.

More info:

http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/download